# OpenOffice DDEExecute Failing

Tags: delphi, openoffice-calc, dde

My Delphi application currently sends the command '[File.CLOSE()]' to Excel using DDEExecute.

I want to run the application in an environment where Excel licensing is an issue so we're trying to use OpenOffice. If it matters, we're using LibreOffice.

When I try to run the same command to the sOffice DDE server it fails with the following error:

```
16393   DMLERR_NOTPROCESSED Receiving task was not interested in message.
```

I can successfully pull data from the spreadsheet using DDERequest so I know that my configuration is correct.

I suspect that my problem may be because File.CLOSE() is some sort of macro or VBA command which doesn't exist in OpenOffice. If that's the case, are there some other commands I can use to the same effect?

Comment: An application has to be designed to support DDE. Excel is (as DDE was a Microsoft technology long since abandoned). Apparently OO does not support it (as the error message indicates, it *was not interested*, meaning it didn't respond to DDE). I'm not aware of any support in OO apps for DDE; it's a long-ago technology that was replaced with COM automation many years ago.

Comment: @Ken *I can successfully pull data from the spreadsheet using DDERequest so I know that my configuration is correct.*

Comment: @David: Then *apparently OO does not support* `File.CLOSE()`.

Comment: @Ken That would appear to be so

Comment: @David: Then I don't understand your point. That was in my initial comment: *Apparently OO doesn't support it* refers to *the command `[File.CLOSE()]`*.

Comment: Maybe it would be more constructive if either of you could provide any useful comment on the question rather than sniping at each other? Private chat facilities are available on Stack Exchange.

Comment: I agree with @Dan, comment 5 and onwards should be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenOffice uses 'OpenOffice Basic', previously known as StarBasic. So it does not understand the command 'File.CLOSE()'.

The corresponding OpenOffice Basic command is 'thisComponent.close(true)'.

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide